# Meteor: write to database on successful callback from server method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to write to database only on successful callback received from server when I invoke it from client.

```
    Meteor.call('job', 'new', name, script, function(err,response) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Error while processing your script. Please make sure syntax is correct.')
            return;
        }else{
            taskid = response;
            console.log(taskid);
            FileSystem.update({ _id: this.params.fileId }, { $set: { content: content, taskid:taskid} }, function (e, t) {
                if (e) {
//error
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

write now it says

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'job': TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileId' of undefined
```

I expected that it will only update the DB when the server call was successful. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Is this inside of a Route? Where does `this.params` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this.params exists at all, you're likely losing your data context inside of these callback functions.  What you want to do is define a variable before your `Meteor.call()` and set that variable to `this.params.fileId`.  You can then use that variable inside of the callback function.

I've shown this in code below.

```
var fileId = this.params.fileId;
Meteor.call('job', 'new', name, script, function(err,response) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Error while processing your script. Please make sure syntax is correct.')
            return;
        }else{
            taskid = response;
            console.log(taskid);
            FileSystem.update({ _id: fileId }, { $set: { content: content, taskid:taskid} }, function (e, t) {
                if (e) {
//error
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```